# Opening a Samba Server file using Mono C# in Mac OS X

Tags: c#, macos, networking, mono, samba

We are using Mono C# to write a service (running in Mac environment) which will read a particular XML file and open the file from the path mentioned in the XML file. The file path can be a local one or ones in Windows FileServer. We are mounting these file servers on Mac using the Samba share (`smb://`).

We use the `Process.Start()` method to open the files in Mono. This approach us working fine for local files i.e for locations like Desktop or `/{user}/Documents/File.txt` but we are unable to open the files from the Mounted file server. We tried giving the file paths in the following formats:

1. `//{ServerName}/{SharedFolderName}/File.txt`
2. `smb://{ServerName}/{SharedFolderName}/File.txt`
3. `//Volumes/{SharedFolderName}/File.txt`

None of these seem to open the file. Please let me know if any of you have tried something similar.

Comment: Try [this link](http://superuser.com/questions/336665/how-to-automount-smb-shared-network-drives-in-mac-os-x-lion) at superuser.com.

Comment: Once it is mounted, you can find it at /Volumes/sharename/File.txt